# Can anyone help me make this function more efficient

Tags: c++, unordered-map

So I am trying to sort through an unordered_map container. The container reads input from a file which is a list of people. Each line in the file will be like `rCB, bIA`, and this will be stored as an element in the map. The second string in each element acts as a pointer to the next person in the list, so later on it will appear again in a new line, in this case:`bIA,TDV`.

So far I can sort through in order by creating an unordered_map iterator and using the second string in the find function for the iterator to go to the next element. My problem is going the other way. I am able to sort through the opposite way but the way i have implemented my solution means that it takes a very long time to eventually sort through, as we have input files of 3 million people.

```
list<string> SortEast(unordered_map<string, string> &TempUMap, unordered_map<string, string>::iterator IT, list<string> &TempList)
{
    IT = TempUMap.begin();
    while (TempList.size() != (TempUMap.size() + 1))
    {
        if (IT->second == TempList.front())
        {
            TempList.emplace_front(IT->first);
            IT = TempUMap.begin();
        }
        IT++;
    }
    return TempList;
}
```

I've tried to make this more efficient but I cannot think of how. If i could find the value that would go at the start of the list I could sort in order starting with that value, but again I dont know how I would find this value easily.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
A sample of one of our input is:

`rBC,biA
vnN,CmR
CmR,gnz
Dgu,OWn
lnh,Dgu
OWn,YMO
YMO,SIZ
XbL,Cjj
TDV,jew
iVk,vnN
wTb,rBC
jew,sbE
sbE,iVk
Cjj,wTb
AGn,XbL
gnz,SMz
biA,TDV
SIZ,uvD
SMz,lnh`

This is only 20 people. In this case `AGn` is the first value and `uvD` is the last. The output I end up with is:

`AGn
XbL
Cjj
wTb
rBC
biA
TDV
jew
sbE
iVk
vnN
CmR
gnz
SMz
lnh
Dgu
OWn
YMO
SIZ
uvD`

As this file starts with `rBC`, that is the point at which i need to sort backwards

Comment: see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "*So I am trying to sort through an unordered_map container.*" ... why? If you wanted sorting, you should have used a regular `map`.

Comment: @NicolBolas The file that contains the input data is unordered. so it needs to be sorted. Thats why i use an unordered_map. I sort through it and then create a list with the sorted values.

Comment: @eyllanesc should I have posted my question on that website instead?

Comment: @OscarKohn: "*The file that contains the input data is unordered*" That *not* what the "unordered" part of `unordered_map` means. It means that the data you store will be stored in an arbitrary order. If you want to store it in a *sorted* order, you use a sorted map, like `map`.

Comment: @OscarKohn I think you should publish it there

Comment: What determines that a value is the first value? It doesn't appear in the second string anywhere in the file? I assume you want the values in order of `["first", "second"], ["second", "third"], ["third", ...], ...`? Your question would be much more clear if you provided an example of the real data you need to process and the result you hope to obtain.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeas i know that is what you should do, but the input file is not in order so when im reading it in, it doesnt matter what order the elements are stored.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the first and seconds are determined by the input file when I read the file into my unordered_map. so before the comma is the first and after is the second.

Comment: @OscarKohn: "*the input file is not in order so when im reading it in, it doesnt matter what order the elements are stored.*" But your overall goal is to have an ordered sequence, right? That's *what `map` does!* The class *does not care* about the order you insert the items into the container; when you iterate through it, they *will* be in order (by key).

Comment: @NicolBolas But the order I'm trying to sort to isn't what you are describing. Correct me if I'm wrong but if a Map was to sort by key they would be in alphabetical order. I dont want this, I am looking for the second string in each element as the next item in the order. so from the input i showed you get the list of each person in the order they would be if this was the case

Comment: I'm still confused by what you mean by "As this file starts with rBC, that is the point at which i need to sort backwards", but why can't you just walk through the data in order like this?  https://ideone.com/CiyIhH

Comment: Can you just sort the normal way and then walk backwards through that list when you need to go in reverse? Use *reverse iterators*?

Comment: The data you provided is completely circular - so it doesn't matter what value you start with. Is that always going to be true or is that just a coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply do something like this:

```
vector<string> orderAllTheNames(const unordered_map<string, string>& input, const string& begin)
{
  vector<string> result;
  result.reserve(input.size());
  string current = begin;

  result.push_back(current);
  while(result.size() < input.size())
  {
    current = input[current];
    result.push_back(std::move(current));
  }
  return result;
}
```

I may have missed some details as I typed this on my phone. You can add some pointers and/or std::moves if you're worried about too many copies flying around.

I guess it's the same as your solution, but without the awkward list and emplace_front.

Comment: wouldn't you need to know which string is going to be the first in the ordered list of people?

Comment: According to your comments the place to start is the first alphabetically. This is simple to keep track of as you load the file and then pass to this function as `begin`.

Comment: The input that i  included is an example of inputs. The first in the list may not be the first alphabetically. Just what happened in this case

Comment: Which is why I asked the very specific question about how you determine that. A question you answered in such a way as to make it seem like the first name in alphabetical order was where to start. This question needs work if you actually want an answer.